# How do I call functions in another child from the child in react native when imported?

Tags: react-native

I have a few custom functional components that I import:

```
        <ProgressSwitch name="first" routeId={route.params.key} />
        <ProgressSwitch name="second" routeId={route.params.key} />
        <ProgressSwitch name="third" routeId={route.params.key} />
```

What is the best way to update them on change of the first one? So if I switch the first switch on, the other 2 would also become true.

**ProgressSwitch:**

```
const ProgressSwitch = props => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    pullRouteProgressFromCloud(props.routeId, props.name, setProgress);
  }, []);

  const SubmitToFireStore = value => {
    setProgress(value);
    pushRouteProgressToCloud(props.routeId, {[props.name]: value});
  };

  return (
    <Switch
      onValueChange={value => SubmitToFireStore(value)}
      value={progress}
    />
  );
};
export default ProgressSwitch;
```

Comment: Use a callback coming from the parent screen / component which holds a boolean state. Then pass this state to childs and use useEffect on it if you want to change the progress

Comment: That sounds like what I want, can you give a quick example of what adding a callback would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// parent
const [mainProgress, setProgress] = useState(false)
...
  <ProgressSwitch name="first" routeId={route.params.key} onSubmit={(value) => setProgress(value)} />
  <ProgressSwitch name="second" routeId={route.params.key} mainProgress={mainProgress} />
  <ProgressSwitch name="third" routeId={route.params.key} mainProgress={mainProgress} />
```

On the child side:

```
// child

useEffect(() => {
  setProgress(props.mainProgress)
}, [props.mainProgress]);

const SubmitToFireStore = value => {
    if (onSubmit) {
      onSubmit(value)
    }
    setProgress(value);
    pushRouteProgressToCloud(props.routeId, {[props.name]: value});
};
```

By the way, you should use TS over JS and type your state. Here, you're mixing boolean and number, which can lead to errors.

With TS:

```
const [mainProgress, setProgress] = useState<number>(0) // <number> is inferred by TS, not mandatory with simple types
```

Comment: What is 'setToggle' in your example?

Comment: I've edited the example.
It was a renaming mistake, it's hard to code outside a real editor ^^